# NGINX Problems in redirect from "/" to "index" when non secure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, configuration, ubuntu-12.04

I've got a personal website running up and going. I've rented a cloud ssd server and configured nginx on it to serve content. All the content which has to be served directly is in the path "/www/public" .

So here comes the issue: when i go to https://www.danielecencig.com I get redirected to the index page (right now you'd see the maintenance but that's correct). While when I go to http://www.danielecencig.com it stays on NGINX welcome page. 
Where was i wrong in my config?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/1_www.danielecencig.com_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;
    server_name www.danielecencig.com; 
    root /www/public;

    rewrite  ^/$  /index.html  permanent;

    location / {
    root /www/public;
        if (-f $document_root/error/maintenance.html) {
        return 503;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }

    location /SienaBikes {
    if (-f $document_root/error/maintenance.html) {
        return 503;
    }
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_page 503 /error/maintenance.html;
    location ^~ /error/ {
    internal;
    root /www/public;
    } 
}
```

Comment: First up, using if and doing the maintenance thing is going to confuse things and could be a potential cause of problems. Nginx does not like "if" - google "Nginx If is evil". Both URLs lead me to a page with the "site maintenance" message, so I'm not really sure what your problem is.

Comment: This now works just fine for me as well.